# How many threads meanwhile run in one clock can the Java program in 1 core docker container

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes

as the title.
I use kubernetes to manage container. And config the pods CPU as one core.
when one docker container generated  by kubernetes in a hyper thread server,so this docker container cpu config is one core.
Then one java programe run in this docker container.
How many threads can this Java program run under the same clock
[image: diagram]

Answer (score 0):

Linux reports HT cores as CPUs so if you request 1 CPU (`cpu: 1000m`) then you can run one thread concurrently, or potentially more if there are unused cores on the machine.